# How to Focus GUI.TextArea in Unity for Android

Tags: android, user-interface, unity-game-engine, unityscript

In Unity Editor, I could focus a GUI.TextArea by doing the following:

```
    GUI.SetNextControlName("MyTextField");
    m = GUI.TextArea(new Rect(0f, 0f, 100f, 100f), m, 64,style);
    GUI.FocusControl("MyTextField");
```

However, this didn't work in Android devices. Instead, I had to tap the text area to focus it and bring up the TouchScreenKeyboard.

What should I do to programmatically set focus on GUI.TextArea for Android devices.

Comment: Dunno if this works, but you could try InputFieldName.select(); InputFieldName.ActivateInputField();